# How to Edit Header Row in Pandas - Styling

Tags: python, css, pandas, header

I understand from here: [How can I change the styles of pandas DataFrame headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115514/how-can-i-change-the-styles-of-pandas-dataframe-headers), that pandas column row is set by the set_table_styles method.  I do not know the HTML code for the table styles.  Can someone please help me simply add a background color black, and white text?

```
df2.style.set_table_styles(
   [{'selector': 'th',
   'props': [('background-color', 'black'),('font color', '#FFFFFF')]}])
```

this does not show the font color.  Is there somewhere I can find a list of these properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Cascading Style Sheets (CSS)

#### Links

1. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/
2. https://cssreference.io/
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

---

You want `'color'` not `'font color'` (IIUC)

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(1, [*'abc'], [*'xyz'])

    df.style.set_table_styles(
       [{
           'selector': 'th',
           'props': [
               ('background-color', 'black'),
               ('color', 'cyan')]
       }])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks pi.  I found the 'color' shortly after asked.  Thanks for the external references.

Comment: Hey, this is great. How would you make edits for only one column instead of all columns simultaneously?

Comment: @dayxx369 Were you able to figure this out? I would like to know how to split a particular cell into 2 columns. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115560/splitting-a-table-cell-into-two-columns-in-html