# How to color labels of the pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are a lot of examples how to color and make another style changes with cells of pandas DataFrame, but how can I do this with it's labels(index or columns)?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243717/python-pandas-style-column-header/55263917#55263917) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693827/how-to-edit-header-row-in-pandas-styling)

Comment: Thank you for references, I will study it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Style column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243717/python-pandas-style-column-header)

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I have already study it following Shijith's lead. Now I know how to operate with columns, even to color column with indexes. But i still wonder how I can do that for current index label.