# How to put a border on a Pandas Dataframe header in Python

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that i want to put a border on. I am currently using the code below which works on the body of the data frame but it doesn't put a border on the header. Any idea how it is possible? Otherwise, is there a workaround?

```
df = df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'white',                                                   
                                'color': 'black',
                                'border': 'black',
                                'border-style' :'solid',
                                'border-color': 'black'})
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but have you seen the next? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115514/how-can-i-change-the-styles-of-pandas-dataframe-headers

Comment: Use `.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('border-color', 'black'), ('border-style','solid')]}])`

Comment: That's great. thanks